# Dependent or Independent samples?

Tags: self-study, independence, paired-comparisons

I have an assignment where I have to determine if the samples are dependent or independent. The sample is of 100 people, where their reaction times from their dominate and non-dominate hands was recorded when an image is flashed in front of them. The results where recorded in seconds. Now because the hands are separate items and results not dependent on on the other ones outcome or reaction time I assume that they are independent. But my friend thinks because they come from the same person they are dependent—e.g., if you take one person away both samples would be effected so they are dependent. I'm so confused!

Comment: Do you have a data set to go along with this assignment?

Comment: The dependence you suggested is also called "repeated measurement" in which the same subject is measured again and again. Yet, dependence can exist in many forms, since both hands are connected to the same nervous system, they can also be considered as dependent. For instance, a younger person may have fast time in both hands, compared to an older subject.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint: if your data points are all sampled independently, that means, roughly, that seeing one data point doesn't tell you anything about other, yet unseen data points (not counting what you learn by using the data to estimate the underlying model). So the question is, if you know somebody's reaction time with one hand, should that information be expected to have any bearing on their reaction time with the other hand?